# Unreliable Wifi on Cyanogenmod

Tags: wi-fi, htc-one, cyanogenmod

I installed Cyanogenmod 11 on an HTC One. There are a few quirks, but mostly everything works. The only real annoying thing is wireless doesn't work reliably.

I have a Netgear N900 wireless router running DD-WRT, and the phone can connect to it, but after a few minutes of inactivity on my phone, the wireless just stops and Cyanogenmod shows the connection as "Saved, secured with WPA2" but I'm unable to bring anything up over wifi. Clicking the wifi point and selecting "Connect to network" does nothing. The only workaround I found is to disable and then re-enable my wifi, and then it automatically reconnects and wifi works.

I confirmed I have "keep wifi active when idle" checked in my settings.

Is this a bug in CM, or do I have something misconfigured? How can I fix it?

Edit: As a workaround, I found the problem disappears if I configure the DD-WRT router to N-only instead of the default auto/mixed mode. I'm still unsure if there's a bug in CM that prevents it from working with the router in auto mode, of if DD-WRT has a bug in it that causes devices to disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you describe could plausibly be caused by a bug in the Wi-Fi software on your phone, if sleeping the Wi-Fi transceiver makes it forget something necessary to make the connection work (such as the WPA keys).

This is the kind of thing you have to expect when you use a pre-release version of a ROM. Nightly builds simply aren't suitable for day-to-day use, because it's a bit of a lottery what bugs will have been added from one build to the next. Switch to a stable build instead.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately, there is no stable CM11 build for the HTC One, and CM11 is the only build that supports it, even though its been available for over a year.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by disabling WiFi password on my router.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue at work by deleting some old wifi access points and rebooting. It may have been I had too many saved. I will try to see if it's fixed for good when I get to my home wifi

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is this a bug in CM, or do I have something misconfigured ?

Ans : This is because probably you are using **[Nightly build](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightly_build)**.

> 2. How can I fix it?

Ans : No you can't.

Piece of advice : 
1. Wait for next build.
2. Avoid nightly builds.